# How to safe delete the usages of struct field on all files from Intellij?

Tags: go, intellij-idea, automated-refactoring, vim-go

Though we have refactoring tool to rename the struct field we do not have refactoring tool for deleting the struct field & its usages.

How to safely delete the struct field and its usages[Write & read access] across the files from any IDE that supports golang?

As far as I have seen none of the IDE(vim-go, intellij) supports this.

I had thought of deleting the struct field & run

`go vet`

which will return all error(along with line number) on every file & write a script to delete those lines but unfortunately vet stops reporting errors after very first error encountered in a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something that could be fully automated. Let's say you remove the field `X` from the type `Point struct {X, Y int}`. What should the IDE do when it's used like this:

```
p := Point{X: 1, Y: 2}
r := p.X / p.Y
```

Or like this:

```
func f(x, y int) {}

f(p.X, p.Y)
```

What's needed is obviously not something the IDE could "guess".

To delete a struct field, delete it from the type definition and proceed to fix the compiler errors manually.

Comment: Is there any tool that can give me all error lines of each file reporting unknown literal by parsing whole project?

Comment: @Mani Build the project with `go build ./...` and it'll give you the errors. IDEs will also show you all the lines where compilation fails.